# Docker exporting container

Tags: docker, migrating

My Docker install has problems and no longer works properly. When I try to use docker export [containername].

I get the following error

FATA[0000] Get http://%2Fvar%2Frun%2Fdocker.sock/v1.18/containers/json: dial unix /var/run/docker.sock: connect: no such file or directory. Are you trying to connect to a TLS-enabled daemon without TLS?

I would like to move the containers on this machine to a new machine that I have setup.

Is there a way to move the containers without using the CLI?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure this is a CLI issue. Technically when you run a `docker` command it goes CLI > API > Docker daemon. Locally, the API is listening on a UNIX socket but your error says there's nothing listening on the socket. Is your Docker daemon running?